# Clear RDP Virtual Channel contents

Tags: c#, c++, rdp

I am developing a tool to communicate strings from a RDP-Client against a RDP-Server.  Communication is done throught RDP Virtual Channels.

It is almost done, but I need to purge virtual channel contents on Server-Start.  I mean,

the first one to going up is the client side, loaded by MSTSC application.  So the server side is always a bit late on the communication interchange.  I need to clear any string communicated before the server side was started.

I have found this purge functions (for server and client sides):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383850(v=vs.85).aspx

But If I use any of them the communication is broken.  No error, but them no message is communicated along sides.  And they have this note in the documentation:

```
'This function currently is not used by Remote Desktop Services.'
```

I am looking for something to use out of the box.  Not something developed by myself.

Thanks.

Comment: If you send "string" before the `CHANNEL_EVENT_CONNECTED`, I am not sure what happens, since the Server side is not here, yet, indeed. But if you wait this event, and only send "strings" afterward, I see no reason to "clear" or "purge" the Channel.